# Assigning Return Values to a Struct (C++)

Tags: c++, struct

I'm fairly new to C++ and I was just learning about structs and enums. I decided to put them into practice and after making a simple program that read user input for different pieces of information about there pet, I came across a bug. Whenever I run my program, it gets the user input and when it prints it out, it just print "NAME: " I think the issue is with me assigning return values to struct members. If so, how would I fix my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ANIMALS.h"

animalType getType();
std::string getName();
int getAge();

int main(){

    yourPet userInput;
    userInput.yourPetsAge = getAge();
    userInput.yourPetsName = getName();
    userInput.yourPetsSpecies = getType();
    std::cout << "This is your pet's info: NAME: ", userInput.yourPetsName,
    " AGE: ", userInput.yourPetsAge, " SPECIES: ", userInput.yourPetsSpecies;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

animalType getType(){
    int speciesChoice;
    std::cout << "What type of pet do you have?\nEnter the corresponding number to        your  pet's species" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1: DOG 2: CAT 3: FISH 4: BIRD" << std::endl;

    std::cin >> speciesChoice;

    if (speciesChoice == 1){
    return DOG;
    }
    if (speciesChoice == 2){
        return CAT;
    }
    if (speciesChoice == 3){
        return FISH;
    }
    if (speciesChoice == 4){
        return BIRD;
    }

}

std::string getName(){
    std::string petName;

    std::cout << "What is your pet's name?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> petName;

    return petName;

}

int getAge(){
    int petAge;

    std::cout << "What is your pet's age?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> petAge;

    return petAge;

}
```

Comment: “I think the issue is with me assigning return values to struct members.” No. It's your wrong usage of the comma operator. `,` isn't the same as `<<`…

Comment: My bad. I just realized that after posting.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<<` to separate outputs, not commas:

```
std::cout << "This is your pet's info: NAME: " << userInput.yourPetsName <<
             " AGE: " << userInput.yourPetsAge << 
             " SPECIES: " << userInput.yourPetsSpecies;

system("PAUSE");
```